# Sorting in ascending order

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Being new to ES6 and JavaScript, when I need to sort an object array by a particular key, I do:

```
objectArray.sort(x=> x.orderKey).reverse();
```

In terms of performance, since the `reverse` methods runs the original array in another loop or it may create some additional temporary variables (however, I'm not sure about its mechanism), I think that this is not the correct solution. Is there any built-in functionality that allows for specifying the descending or ascending order?

Comment: `Array#sort()` requires comparing 2 arguments. What is shown doesn't make much sense. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl: with a single argument I can sort in descending order

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is working different.

You need to specify the order of two given elements and return a value smaller than zero, zero or a value greater than zero, depending on the order of the items.

If `orderKey` is a numerical value, you could return the delta of supposed to be ascending values of

```
objectArray.sort((a, b) => a.orderKey - b.orderKey)
```

For a reverse order, you could swap the calculations operands.

For string values, you could use a comparison

```
objectArray.sort((a, b) => (a, b) => a.orderKey > b.orderKey || -(a.orderKey < b.orderKey))
```

or [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
objectArray.sort((a, b) => a.orderKey.localeCompare(b.orderKey))
```

Comment: I don't understand, if I wanna order based on a string value, then would `string - string` work?

Comment: @dv, needless to ask, or?

Comment: This isn't a good solution, in that case, I'd rather write my own function to do it in a more effective way. I have not tested this yet, but looks slow.

Comment: @Arrrr these words don't make much sense, you won't make it shorter  (or faster) than this solution for sure.

Comment: I'm actually redirecting the stress from server to client, so I'm for top-speed functions, not something that just works

Comment: does speed really matters?

Comment: (except of going and reimplementing the whole sort-function, which I don't think you were going to do, @Arrrr)

Comment: @NinaScholz: In this case it matters to millisecond and that is the problem.

Comment: so the question morphed from a wrong callback to some more efficient approach, which missed the count of items, the structure, why it could not be sorted on the server, etc.

Comment: Using native sort is going to be faster than a custom made one..  but if @Arrrr wants to find this out for himself, good luck bud..

Comment: @Keith: You can only say that if you benchmark two function with proper inputs.

Comment: Well I leave you to prove me wrong..  good luck with that.. :)

Comment: @Keith: I already can, write a quick sort method in C language, and run that and what's mentioned in this answer against the same data. This logic here is way more complicated, it can be simplified to get the performance of C. I don't know what kind of projects you've been dealing with but believing that some function is 100% the best idea or fits all scenarios is not a production-wise idea.

Comment: @Keith: One more issue with this code is that it is ugly, unreadable, and spreads redundant code. I'd prefe  something more like `OrderBy(x=> x.Name, Order.Desc)` to this.

Comment: `Being new to ES6 and JavaScript`  yep,  good advice ignore all those who are not new.  Oh.  I came from c c++ Delphi etc, so try not using that as a badge of honour here, it won't wash.  Make a snippet here that goes faster than native sort, and I'll be impressed, until then you sound like someone who is full of themself.

Comment: @Keith: I see that you are angry? But I don't understand why. I don't know Delphi though, so you are better than me :)

Comment: I'm not angry, If you want the fastest sort in Javascript, you can avoid using the `sort` method, as this is callback based.  But this is the same for C, it's built into sort method had a compare function just like Javascript version.   A custom sort won't have this overhead, so you could try that, and you may gain those milliseconds your after.